# What is the difference between a void* and *(void**)?

Tags: c++, pointers

I was programming an `aligned_malloc` implementation in C++ and mainly use the following code, which can be found in various places on the Interwebs, including SO:

```
void * aligned_malloc(size_t size, int align) {
    if (align < 0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    void *ptr;
    void *p = malloc(size + align - 1 + sizeof(void*));

    if (p != NULL) {
        ptr = (void*) (((ptrdiff_t)p + sizeof(void*) + align -1) & ~(align-1));
        *((void**)((ptrdiff_t)ptr - sizeof(void*))) = p;
        return ptr;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void aligned_free(void *p) {
    void *ptr = *((void**)((ptrdiff_t)p - sizeof(void*)));
    free(ptr);
    return;
}
```

I get the `*(void**)` in the `aligned_malloc`. My misunderstanding is with the cast in the `aligned_free`. Since we just want the value and don't have to assign to it why not use

```
void *ptr = ((void*)((ptrdiff_t)p - sizeof(void*)));
```

instead of

```
void *ptr = *((void**)((ptrdiff_t)p - sizeof(void*)));
```

I thought it was the same but when I tried the first one with an alignment of 64 it gave me an error, but when I tried the second cast the program worked correctly. So what is the difference between the two? I left out the proper C++ casts for the sake of readability.

Comment: Because they're not the same thing.  The second one involves a dereference, i.e. it reads a value stored in memory.

Comment: Could you explain, please? I will update my post with how I understand the two.

Comment: what's wrong with `operator new`, it serves up aligned storage, C++11 §18.6.1/2 "Return a non-null pointer to suitably aligned storage".

Comment: @DavidBos The algebra of pointers involves the rule that `*&a = &*a = a`. There's no rule that `*(T*)a = a`.

Comment: Oh, shit... I had a weird way of thinking about the function. I thought the address at `(ptrdiff_t)p - sizeof(void*)` was always the address returned by `malloc`, which is obviously not true. Sorry, for inconvenience and thanks for freshing things up, I think I will delete the post however since it doesn't really serve any purpose anymore.

Comment: @gnasher729, careful that kind of thinking doesn't lead to a NIH mentality http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here

Comment: @DavidBos Nah, you cannot delete a post if it was answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us simplify the code:

```
int x = 7;
void * p = &x;
void * q = &p;
```

And now let us draw a diagram:

```
  +---+
x | 7 |
  +---+
    ^ 
    |
  +-|-+
p | * |
  +---+
    ^ 
    |
  +-|-+
q | * |
  +---+
```

Do you see how `p` and `q` are not equal? If you have `q`, and you want to get to `p`, you have to dereference `q`. But since a `void*` cannot be dereferenced, you have to promise the type system that it will find another pointer after the dereference, hence the cast to `void**` before the dereference.

```
assert(q != p);
assert(*(void**)q == p);
```

Comment: Yes, I just got it. I had the function wrong in my head. I thought the address returned by `malloc` always was equal to `(ptrdiff_t)p - sizeof(void*)` which caused my confusion. I get it now though. Thanks! I accepted your answer but the original question relies more on my mistake and not much on the pointers. Should I keep the question alive?

Answer (score 1):

Should be clearer if you replace

```
void *ptr = *((void**)((ptrdiff_t)p - sizeof(void*)));
```

with the equivalent

```
void *ptr = ((void**)((ptrdiff_t)p - sizeof(void*))) [0];
```

The * is not part of any cast, it is dereferencing a pointer. It's reading data from memory.

On the other hand, you should get a really good book about C++ and look at the functions that are built into the C++ library. That's much more likely to work without problems. Using malloc_aligned means you have two classes of pointers, those allocated by malloc and those allocated by malloc_aligned, and both are incompatible.